# Sharepoint 2010 metadata filters- Driving from a link or script

Tags: jquery, list-view, filter, metadata

The "old style" list filters in Sharepoint List views (e.g. when the user clicks on a column to filter or sort on column values) use an http GET, so the filter paramaters are transmitted in the page URL.

This makes it easy to copy the URL to use in a link that will show the list in as a "canned filter" view. I.e. if I have a library with documents marked as (say) "draft" or "final", I can easily create a link that shows a list of **final** documents only.

The "new style" metadata key filters (the ones that display in the list view sidebar) use POST to communicate with the server.

Has anyone managed to reverse-engineer this mechanism and the parameters to be able to drive it via custom links? (say by putting a # address in the URL, and a piece of jquery to parse out the filter values and apply them).

Looking at the POST data there are some visible filter values in there, but there's also a whole slew of other (encoded) form data, and it's not clear how much of it is required for the server to take the POST as a valid filter request.

If someone has seen this done, I would really appreciate a pointer to a recipe.